# Webzash on CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, accounting

I have a working CakePHP (2.5.6) project having Webzash (accounting software) installed and running as a plugin.

Now I want to add a new type of report in that Webzash but I am just unable to even edit the existing reports in the Webzash.

Does anyone know how to add/edit a plugin running on CakePHP ? Or is Webzash even editable ?!

I have been reading the Cookbook (2.x) and looking for solutions online but to no avail so here I am with my first ever question.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Note: I tried adding the Webzash tag to this question but it doesn't let me as I don't have enough points. So if anyone can do that, they are welcome as it will help people in future as well :-)

**Update:**

Error: The action cashflow is not defined in controller ReportsController

Error: Create ReportsController::cashflow() in file: app/Controller/ReportsController.php

```
`<?php
class ReportsController extends AppController {
public function cashflow() {
}
}`
```

- My code at app/Plugin/Webzash/Controller/ReportsController.php (since all other methods are called from this same controller)

  `class ReportsController extends WebzashAppController {
  public function cashflow() {
  $this->set('title_for_layout', __d('webzash', 'Cashflow'));
  /* POST */
  ...
  }
  }`
- The routes at app/Plugin/Webzash/Config/routes.php

  `Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'webzash'));
  Router::connect('/:controller/*', array('plugin' => 'webzash', 'action' => 'index'));
  Router::connect('/*', array('plugin' => 'webzash', 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'));`

**Last Update:**

Just to let you all in need know that with the help of the original developer, Prashant Shah, I have set up

1. A cashflow statement
2. New accounting year with data carry forward from the previous year.

on Webzash. Let me know if anybody needs help regarding this :)

Comment: `(0.2.9)` is this _really_ the version of CakePHP you are using? That's about 10 years old.

Comment: Yes it is! All I have to do is add a new report in the plugin (Webzash) this project has and can't find any help about this Webzash.

Comment: The docs you are reading are for a completely different version, and there is no code in the question.

Comment: Oh well ... they at least taught me the CakePHP and how it works :P what to read now ? but I need to know about Webzash though.

Comment: SORRY! I feel embarrassed now that I typed the @since version here !! It is 2.5.6 in reality :P I just checked again because the docs were making sense according to the project structure. Thank you for pointing that out!!

Comment: We can't really help you if you don't provide any error messages or code. What makes it that you can't edit existing reports?

Comment: Thank you, Koen, for letting me know the right way to ask question.
This is the plugin that is working in my CakePHP plugins folder for the accounting purposes https://webzash.org/download
When I try to edit any file in it (I want to add cash flow statement) in any folder (model or controller or view), it doesn't show up online. The code is edited but looks like making no change. There isn't any error generated either which I can post here or can give me a clue to solve this issue.
Maybe this plugin/accounting software isn't editable? I am unable to find help regarding Webzash actually.